# SQLite sql query didn't return randomly one record

Tags: sql, sqlite

I expect to get different records from the query whenever i run it. But some of records returned twice or more. How the logic must settled to get randomly just one record per loop over this query?

`//Looping starts here`

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT *,ims_2012_modifiye.id AS imsID, ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id AS ilacID, ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_adi_duzgun AS iaDuzgun 
FROM ims_2012_modifiye 
LEFT JOIN ilaclar ON ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id=ilaclar.id WHERE ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOTNULL AND ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt<1 AND ims_2012_modifiye.asil_listede_mi=1 AND ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id 
NOT IN(SELECT ilac_id FROM piyasa_kontrol WHERE pk_yil IN (2010,2011,2012)) OR ims_2012_modifiye.oncelik_verilsin_mi=1 
LIMIT 10
)ORDER BY random() LIMIT 0,1
//Updating pk_2013_1qrt to 1 here
//Looping Ends here
```

Also i update `pk_2013_1qrt` field to `1` after every query to sure not to get same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to

- Use GROUP BY
- Use DISTINCT

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you but. I need to know which record has selected (by updating its pk_2013_1qrt field) before, so i can't use `distinct` here.

Comment: What about GROUP BY?, also, can you provide an example of duplicated registers?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt AS durum,ims_2012_modifiye.id AS imsID, ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id AS ilacID, ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_adi_duzgun AS iaDuzgun 
  FROM ims_2012_modifiye 
  LEFT JOIN ilaclar ON ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id=ilaclar.id 
  WHERE ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOTNULL 
  AND pk_2013_1qrt<1
  AND ims_2012_modifiye.asil_listede_mi=1 
  AND ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOT IN(SELECT ilac_id FROM piyasa_kontrol WHERE pk_yil IN (2010,2011,2012))
    OR ims_2012_modifiye.oncelik_verilsin_mi=1 
    LIMIT 10
)ORDER BY random() LIMIT 0,10`